# How do you change the url of "continuous-integration/jenkins" in a github PR?

Tags: jenkins, ghprb

When we create a github PR, our builds automatically kick off. Cool.

We would like to tweak the link that the "details" button points to.

How do you do that?
[image]

We can change the text via https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-scm-trait-notification-context-plugin, but we would like to tweak the actual link that "details" points to.